# Save Files from Webserver to a Homeserver?

Tags: web-server, website

I hired a webserver, where my website is running.
The Hoster gives me a maximum of 50GB WebSpace.

Now the Problem is: I need more!

But I don't want to change the Hoster.

Is it possible to save Files from Website/Webserver to a HomeServer/my own PC?

Comment: I presume you have FTP access, so could you not just download files using FTP to your home machine? Or is this about serving files from your home PC (which not *not* the best idea). Or you could stump up the money needed...

Comment: The Users on my Website can Download and Upload Files.. i could download these Files over FTP.. But they must still be online for all users..

Comment: So you want to be able to use your home server as an "expansion" for the upload space? Probably won't be seamless...and no way reliable. But we'll have to see if any answers get posted.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want.. I also asked the same on Stackoverflow.. Someone told me I should use a cloud Service, where I can upload a lot of data for very cheap, I will see

Comment: FYI, ServerFault was the right place to post this question. Amazon or Azure would be possible to use, although it depends on the nature (and I expect, legality), of the uploaded files.

Comment: How fast is the link between your home and your hosting company?  If they are large files and the link is relatively slow (especially upload) that may be your determining factor.  I would look into FUSE and SSHFS or a VPN solution to do the actual storage sharing.

Comment: @tombull89: Of course its legal :) .. The Problem is that Amazon is still quite expensive. to d34dh0r53: mhm I don't know how fast it is (how could I check this?) , and no, that aren't large files (up to 100-200MB)

Comment: Ok, let's look at it this way. How long would it take for users to download files from your website, and how long would it take to download (upload) from your server? Put a 100MB file on the server and on your PC and ask someone to see how long they take to download.

Comment: The Site is not online at the Moment, but I know its really fast..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question (and the comment discussion) basically boils down to "I have a website where users upload stuff.  I want to be able to store more stuff, but my ISP's quota is too low to allow that. What do I do?"

The (right) answer is simple: Buy more disk space (your ISP will almost certainly be willing to sell it to you!) or move the site to a provider who will give you adequate space.

If you want to go with hackery you can easily set up space on Amazon EC2 or similar services or write up some custom store-and-retrieve scripts and use your home machine (or something like rsync.net) to provide back-end storage, but this always risks a disruption between the back-end storage and the front-end web server, and as tombull89 pointed out many home ISPs have a "no servers" clause (using your system as back-end storage could be construed as violating such a clause, in which case you can kiss your internet connection goodbye...)

You're almost always going to be better off using a hosting service that is capable of meeting your needs rather than trying to home-grow a solution.